# For each loop: changing values of a nested array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am having difficulties in changing the values of a nested array. I am trying to change the `'admin' => '1'`value to `'admin' => '0'` of each nested array. I tried a foreach loop but the logic is not correct. How can I correct this? or is there a better way?

Array

```
'user' => array(
        // Regular user, admin
    array(
       'id' = '1'
       'admin' => '1',
       ),
    array(
        'id' = '2'
        'admin' => '1',
        ),
    array(
       'id' = '3'
       'admin' => '1',
       ),
    )
```

Loop:

```
foreach ($users as $admin => $value) {
        if ($value == 1) {
            $value == 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the value by reference if you want to edit it in the source array.

```
foreach ($users as $admin => &$value) {
    if ($value['admin'] == 1) {
        $value['admin'] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the type of admin twice (`==`). You need the assignment statement of `=`. 
You also need to access the `admin` key of the array you are looping on.

This should be more like it:

```
foreach ($users as $admin => $value) {
        if ($value['admin'] == 1) {
//                ^ Use ['key'] to access the value of that key 
            $value['admin'] = '0';
//                          ^ This assigns 0 to the value.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to pass 'admin' key for $value in foreach statement

use

```
      $value['admin']
```